# Compile a list of sites using SSLv2 through TLS 1.2 using wget

Tags: shell, ssl, wget

I am trying to use the wget command with a large input file to determine which URLs use SSLv2 or SSLv3. I would like a script to then interpret the wget results and output a separate logfile with a simple list. Example: SSLv2: 5,000, SSLv3 10,000.

My wget command looks like this:

## wget -i /~/test.txt --spider -S --secure-protocol=SSLv2 -o /~/testout.txt

What am I missing?

The test.txt file is a long list of URLs compiled from the Alexa database. Also, I am not sure where to begin with a script. Can I use AppleScript with the testout.txt file or should I be using a bash shell within the wget command?

Comment: Are you sure that your wget can actually still do SSLv2? Most SSL stacks (like OpenSSL) do not compile support for SSLv2 in by default any more.

Comment: I am using wget v1.16 which is still supporting SSLv2. I tested it on several webistes and received the '200OK' connection status.